# Initialising a function returns it's name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({ default: () => callApiHere(), defaultTab: " });

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state, 'current state values')
}, [state])
```

The problem here is whenever I do a setState the Api call isn't happening properly. It returns me the function name callApiHere itself in the console.log

Comment: Add more code. How you trying to setState? How you trying to call that api function and etc.

Comment: Could you share more? Are you doing this: ‘console.log(state.default());’ Also, what is your use case? An API function in State is probably not a good idea (as a general rule) could you explain why this was done this way?

Comment: For `defaultTab` you are using a single double quotes mark instead of double single quotes.

Comment: `const [state, setState] = React.useState(() => callApiHere());`

Answer (score 2):

Make api calls in useEffects or event handlers

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({ 
     default: {}, // set default value here
     defaultTab: "" 
 });

useEffect(() => {
   let ignore = false;

   const fetchData = async () => {
       const response = await callApiHere();
       // skip execution in invalid scope
       if (ignore) { return; } 
       setState(s => ({ ...s, default: response }))
   } 

   fetchData()

   return () => {
       ignore = true;
   }
   
}, [])
```

when using `state` use [chaining](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-optional-chaining/) `?.` or `??` to handle missing data accordingly

```
{ state?.default?.property ?
  <div>...</div>
 : null
}
```

You can check the [beta docs about useEffect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects) life cycles

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but I want to initialize the state's default value before the useEffect runs so that it won't return an undefined error.

Comment: @Ryuzaki you can't do that

Comment: Welcome @Ryuzaki I edited the answer to provide some points on handling missing data

Comment: @Ryuzaki you just have to await the data from API to return, until that has happened you put Loading screen to inform the user that a request has been made